# What's the notion of input size for Quantum Verification?

Tags: complexity-theory

I've been looking into $\mathsf{QPIP}_\tau$ as a complexity class. The following will be a summary of definition 3.12 in [Classical Verification of Quantum Computations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.01082) by Urmila Mahadev.

> A language $L$ is said to have a Quantum Prover Interactive Proof ($\mathsf{QPIP}_\tau$ ) with completeness $c$
>   and soundness $s$ (where $c − s$ is at least a constant) if there exists a pair of algorithms $(P, V)$, where $P$ is the
>   prover and $V$ is the verifier, with the following properties:
>
> 1. The prover $P$ is a $\mathsf{BQP}$ machine, which also has access to a quantum channel which can transmit $\tau$ qubits.
> 2. The verifier $V$ is a hybrid quantum-classical machine. Its classical part is a $\mathsf{BPP}$ machine. The quantum
>      part is a register of $\tau$ qubits, on which the verifier can perform arbitrary quantum operations and which has
>      access to a quantum channel which can transmit $\tau$ qubits. At any given time, the verifier is not allowed to
>      possess more than $\tau$ qubits. The interaction between the quantum and classical parts of the verifier is the
>      usual one: the classical part controls which operations are to be performed on the quantum register, and
>      outcomes of measurements of the quantum register can be used as input to the classical machine.
> 3. There is also a classical communication channel between the prover and the verifier, which can transmit
>      polynomially many bits at any step.
> 4. At any given step, either the verifier or the prover perform computations on their registers and send bits and
>      qubits through the relevant channels to the other party.

There are some more details regarding defining $c$ and $s$, but these are unimportant for my question.
Additionally, it should suffice to take $\tau = 0$, and let $V$ be a $\mathsf{BPP}$ machine that has entirely classical communication with $P$.

---

I'm curious about how specifically the classical part of $V$ is supposed to manipulate the input.
The setting for this paper is taking arbitrary $L\in\mathsf{BQP}$ and reducing it to 2-Local Hamiltonian (where the non-identity parts are Pauli $X$ and $Z$ gates), which is $\mathsf{QMA}$-complete.
This means that the initial input $L$ is specified as some polynomial-size quantum circuit, which must be reduced (in quantum polynomial time) to a local hamiltonian instance.

I have issues understanding how $V$ (in the case when $\tau = 0$, so $V$ is just a $\mathsf{BPP}$ machine) can preform this reduction, or even more generally hold the quantum circuit. Each of the (polynomially many) gates in the circuit is a quantum gate, which for a $n$-qubit system would be of size $2^n\times 2^n$. I feel like $V$ can't have an input of this size, because then the input size is exponential in $n$ (which would cause all sorts of issues with restricting $V$ to be poly-time in the input).

I could see each of (polynomial many) gates $U_i$ being written as a product of (polynomial many) universal gates from some fixed, finite set of gates (or even some gate set of size $\mathsf{poly}(n)$ --- it shouldn't matter). This would mean that the input to $V$ is small enough such that "polynomial time in the input" is a reasonable restriction.

1. Under such a restriction, can a $\mathsf{BPP}$ verifier $V$ reduce the circuit $L$ to $2$-Local Hamiltonian?
2. Additionally, while such a restriction is natural to me, is this how it is typically done? Specifically, how are quantum circuits generally input to classical machines?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes to both questions. See page 2 of [Bookatz's *QMA-Complete Problems*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.6312.pdf), which states:

> When
>   a problem is given a unitary or quantum circuit, $U_x$, it is assumed that the problem is actually given
>   a classical description $x$ of the corresponding quantum circuit, which consists of $\mathsf{poly}(|x|)$ elementary
>   gates. Likewise, quantum channels are specified by efficient classical description.

So the input to $V$ is entirely classical, and polynomial-sized in $|x|$, which is usually taken to be the input to the circuit (and therefore the number of qubits).

As for a verifier being able to reduce things to 2 local Hamiltonian, this is also yes. This picture is from [3-Local Hamiltonian is QMA Complete](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0302079.pdf), and constructs a 3-Local Hamiltonian entirely from projections and $U_i$'s. As the various $U_i$'s are efficiently representable classically (and I assume projections onto the computational basis are as well), it appears a $\mathsf{P}$ machine should be able to construct the local Hamiltonian efficiently (given the classical description of $U_x$, likely with respect to a fixed universal gate set).

Note that the below construction is for 3 Local Hamiltonian, and while the construction for 2 Local Hamiltonian is more technical, I see no difficulties in extending the above argument.

[image]